# Tableau Connection to Microsoft SQL Server 2017

Tags: tableau-api

I would like to connect my Microsoft SQL Server database to Tableau. However, I'm getting the following error when trying to make the connection:

> An error occurred while communicating with Microsoft SQL Server.
>   Unable to connect to the server. Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.
>
> Error Code: 37CE01A3
>   [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_ENV failed
>   Unable to connect to the Microsoft SQL Server server "DESKTOP-2L863I0\SQLEXPRESS". Check that the server is running and that you have access privileges to the requested database.

Is there anything else I need to do within Microsoft SQL Server to allow this connection. Database is locally hosted on my computer and uses standard port.

[image]

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

there were two drivers installed hence why when connecting there was a clash.To resolve this I needed to go to 'Apps & Features' and uninstall one of the drivers (ODBC driver for SQL).

reference to https://kb.tableau.com/articles/issue/error-driver-s-sqlallochandle-on-sql-handle-env-failed